# How to convert Database Query Builder to Database Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

How to convert Database Query Builder to Database Eloquent?

```
$products = DB::table('carts')
                ->join('products','.carts.product_id','=','products.id')
                ->where('carts.user_id',$userID) ->select('products.*')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this article on [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference. You might want to consider updating your question too.

Comment: After setting relations described in @Unflux 's answer, you can convert your code exactly to:

`$products = Product::whereHas('carts', function ($query) use ($userId) {return $query->where(['user_id' => $userId])})->get();`.

Answer (score 1):

As you've provided very little information to assist you with, some assumptions are going to be made such as naming conventions and relationship types.

**Product.php**

Add a `carts` relationship to your `Product` model. This assumes a `Product` can belong to many `Carts`.

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class);
}
```

**Cart.php**

Add a `products` relationship to your `Cart` model. This assumes a `Cart` can have many `Products`.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Create a pivot table which will maintain the relationships between `Carts` and `Products`:

```
php artisan make:migration create_cart_product_table
```

Then add your relationship foreign keys to the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cart_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('cart_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

To add `Products` to a `Cart`, you can use the `attach` or `sync` methods, for example:

```
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(5)->pluck('id');

Cart::create(['user_id' => 1])->products()->attach($products);
```

The above will get 5 `Products` (at random) from your `products` table, then create a new `Cart` with the given `user id` and attach those `Products` to the `Cart`.

To retrieve a `Cart` and it's associated `Products`, you would do the following:

```
$cart = Cart::where('id', $id)->with('products');
```

The `$cart` variable can be passed to a view or in a `json` response where after you can iterate over the `Products` in the `Cart`.

```
$cart = Cart::where('id', $id)->with('products');

return view('cart', compact('cart'));
```

**blade view**

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($cart->products as $product)
    <li>{{ $product->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

If you want to get all the `Cart` records for a given `User`, you would do the following:

```
$carts = Cart::where('user_id', $id)->with('products')->get();

return view('carts', compact('carts'));
```

**blade view**

```
@foreach ($carts as $cart)
    {{ $cart->id }}
    <ul>
        @foreach ($cart->products as $product)
        <li>{{ $product->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <hr />
@endforeach
```

Or something to that effect.